# How can I get GPU information?

Tags: c++, windows, gpu

I have a task to collect information about GPU in Windows with C++ and I don't know where to start! Any idea?

Update: I want name, vram, dac, manufacturer, version, clock.

update2: If I use win32_videocontroller class, I just got the currently used video card's properties, but I need all video card's properties if there are more.

Comment: What sort of information do you need? `GetDeviceCaps` is a really trivial way to get some basic information (e.g., current vertical/horizontal resolution) but it's hard to guess whether that's the sort of information you want or not.

Comment: Name,Vram,DAC,version,manufacturer,clock

Comment: and also how can I  determine how many display device in gpu?

Comment: Unfortunately, Windows doesn't provide much support for retrieving all that information. You can get quite a bit of information about an nVidia GPU with [NVML](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/assets/cuda/files/CUDADownloads/NVML/nvml.pdf). Offhand I don't know of a direct analog to that for Intel, AMD, etc., GPUs though.

Comment: Use DirectX caps queries

Comment: Can you give directx caps documentation link or some information about  it ? :)

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb152827%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Some of the things you want don't exist, at least not universally.  Some GPUs have multiple different clocks.  Others don't have fixed-size VRAM.  Laptop configurations may conceivably have absolutely no DAC at all, if the display accepts digital data.

Comment: You might consider [OpenCL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenCL) (which might work also outside of Windows; e.g. on Linux)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I had a similar problem to solve and I used OpenCL to get the job done. One issue I had though was that in order for the hardware to get detected correctly, I needed my end-user to install OpenCL runtime drivers on their computer, otherwise, on some computers, the detection wouldn't work. I was wondering if there is a better solution that doesn't require a whole library/ecosystem to be installed to just detect the GPUs, CPUs etc.  Just fishing for some thoughts or ideas!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might want to use WMI and Win32_VideoController class.

[Win32_VideoController class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394512(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: I tried it before but  it didn't work with AdapterRam and etc. it didnt return the value and it was the same  with some others

Comment: [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa390423%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) I use this code and If I request AdapterRam it wont give anything back (ofc I wrote the wql querry to win32_displaycontroller......

Comment: Are you running your application with admin privileges? It might be required.

Comment: The link above is actually to the [Win32_VideoController](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394512%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) class, not to the obsolete `Win32_DisplayControllerConfiguration` class.

Comment: well I got some information from the   Win32_VideoController , I only  have problems with few which i needed, so you mean when I run my application in VS with admin priv. or should I  start the VS as admin?

Comment: @user3540983 if you're running a debug version from the VS, you must restart VS with admin rights.

Comment: hr = pclsObj->Get(searchParameter, 0, &vtProp, 0, 0); (hr Hresult) and hr is false after it and the searchParameter was AdapterRam and my wql is Select * from Win32_VideoController... I really don't get it why  I have problems with specific members of this videocontroller

Comment: What does GetLastError() return after the Get() call?

Comment: btw how can I get other video card's data, i mean it gives back the currently used video card's properties

Answer (score 1):

Start with: [IDirect3D9::GetAdapterIdentifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb174317(v=vs.85).aspx)

The perhaps: [IDXGIAdapter::GetDesc](http://IDXGIAdapter::GetDesc%20method)

And if you are on Windows 8: [IDXGIAdapter2::GetDesc2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh404540(v=vs.85).aspx) returns some more information

This should at least get you some rudimentary information like name, vendor, and features of the graphics card. Not sure about vram/dac/clock.